# Azure Remote App inside my Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, azure, remoteapp

I want crate application in which i want to have azure remote app .

let us consider the below scenario:

I have implemented the Designer application (report designer) in WPF. now i creating the website,user of this website need to design the report using the report designer application and host in my website. I planed to host my application in azure remote app using this remote app inside my remote application

Is this possible to do that ? if not how can i achieve that my client need both report designer interface and my web application?

Comment: You can do this with Thinfinity VirtualUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure RemoteApp clients do not have an API today that allows you to input parameters (i.e.: username, password) and also there is no HTML5 client that you could embed in your website. So, I believe it is not possible to do that right now.

/cd